# plot roc curve of diffenret models on same graphics

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification, curve, roc

how to plot roc curves of different models on same graphics please?
I did this but how to continue please!,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
probaA= model.predict_proba(X_testA)[:, 1]
probaB = model.predict_proba(X_testB)[:, 1] 
fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_testA,  probaA)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_testA, probaA)
pyplot.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--')
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="auc="+str(auc))
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display multiple curves in the same figure first create an axis object using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Using the axis object (ax) plot the things you want:

```
ax.plot(fpr_1,tpr_1,label="auc="+str(auc))
ax.plot(fpr_2,tpr_2,label="auc="+str(auc))
```

The curves for model 1 (fpr_1, tpr_1) and model 2 (fpr_2, tpr_2) should appear in the same figure